# How to change img src from $.getJSON?

Tags: image, getjson, src

I want to change the content of `img src` (on HTML code) using JS and JSON, but I can't get.

There are two `$.getJSON` call are due to I don't know get in the same call, get an array and an object, sorry for this bad code but I want to remember you  this is not problem (this piece of code it's rough, but it works)

The problem:

When click on `fa fa-search-plus fa-3x` icon  call to `$('.imagen-go').click(function()`, that replace (will should) `imagen-to-show` on Dialog page (use JQM 1.4.5 sintax), this way it will show the image that came from JSON.

I think:  as `$.getJSON` are async, before to get `files = files['files'];`  JS  run rest of code (more faster that  `$.getJSON`) when it  to reach the variable `subLoc8` is still empty. Please, also read my notes on inline code for well understanding.

How I can to resolve?

JS code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page-1", function( event ) {

var parser_origin = 'http://xxxxxx.com';
var path_thumb1 = '/upload_menus/thumb1/' + id_establecimiento() +'/';
var img_tmpl = '/upload_tmpl/upload.jpg';


   //get data[] (array). 1er JSON. start
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v137/lacarte.restaurants.back/alacarte/php/r.shw.menu.php", { site: id_establecimiento(),idioma: to_translate(),traduccion: traduc_usada() }, function(data){

          for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
              console.log(data[i]);
          }
              data = data['data']; 

    //get files{} (object) . 2nd JSON. start
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v137/lacarte.restaurants.back/alacarte/php/r.shw.menu.php", { site: id_establecimiento(),idioma: to_translate(),traduccion: traduc_usada() }, function(files){ //files // ori

            for (var z=0, len=files.length; z < len; z++) {
              console.log(files[z]); //required!!
                }
            files = files['files']; 

// Now two nested $.each(), to iterate on 1st JSON and get objects of 2nd JSON. It`s work fine!

// 1st loop. sections 
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
collapsible.push(v.es_un); 

$.each(collapsible, function (i, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, seccion) === -1) {
        seccion.push(v);
    }
    });
});

// 2nd loop. items into sections 
$.each(seccion, function (i, loc) {
var parent = loc;
var elements = '';

$.each(data, function (x, sub) {
    var subLoc = sub.nombre;
    var subLoc2 = sub.condimentos;
    var subLoc5 = sub.DT_RowId; 
    var subLoc6 = sub.alergeno; 
    var subLoc7 = sub.nota_item; 
    var subLoc8 = sub.image; 
    // check if have a picture  
      if  (subLoc8 == null || subLoc8 == '')   {
          var foto_mostrar_listview = img_tmpl;  // if not, assign a dummy image for not empty  
        }
      else if  (subLoc8 != null){// if, yes, get it 
          var foto_mostrar_listview = files.files_menus[subLoc8].web_path_thumb2;
        };

    var foto_f = '<img src="'+ foto_mostrar_listview +'" alt="img25"/>';        


    if (sub.es_un == parent) {

                elements += '<li class="ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child">'+ foto_f +'<h2>'+ subLoc + '</h2><h3>' + subLoc2 + '<h3><p>' + '</p><h6><h6><h1 class="ui-li-aside" style="right:0.80em">' + '<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+ '<span class="notranslate">' + items + '<span></h1>' + '</li><a href="#popupPhotoPortrait" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="imagen-go" id="' + subLoc8 + '"><span class="fontawesome"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></p>' 
                items++;  

    } //end if (sub.es_un)

});//$.each(data...)

$("#location-list").append($("<div/>").append($("<div/>", {
    "data-role": "collapsible", 
    "data-collapsed": "true", 
        "data-collapsed-icon": "carat-r", 
        "data-expanded-icon": "carat-d", 
        "class": parent,
        "style" : "margin : 8px 4px"  
}).append($("<h3/>").text(parent)).append($("<ul/>", { 
         "data-role": "listview", 
        "data-theme": "e",
        "data-count-theme": "b",
 }).append(elements).listview()))).collapsibleset('refresh');  

}); //$.each(seccion,...)


    }); //fin del getJSON files{}
    });  //fin del getJSON data[]

});// end ( document ).on

$('.imagen-go').click(function() {

        var id= $(this).attr("id"); 
        var extension =  ".jpg";
        document.getElementById('imagen-to-show').src = path_thumb1 + id + extension ;  // ori

}); // end ('.imagen-go')
```

HTML: focus on issue (Dialog page):

```
...
<!-- DIALOG page. Show picture. start -->

          <div data-role="dialog" id="popupPhotoPortrait" class="photopopup" data-overlay-theme="a"  data-corners="false" data-tolerance="30,15">
          <a href="#" data-rel="back" 
          class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-left">Close</a>
          <img src="" alt="Foto del item" id="imagen-to-show" style="width: 100%">
          </div><!-- /Dialog --> 
...
```

JSON OUTPUT: focus on variables relative to above code. From 1er JSON and 2nd JSON

```
"web_path_thumb2":"\/upload_menus\/thumb2\/342800010\/748.jpg", //2nd JSON

"image":"757"  // 1st JSON
```

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the solution: put inside of $.getJSON calls, the funtion that detect the click on button that show the image (take "id" value from JSON).

Here the  final code that works!!:

Regards

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page-1", function( event ) {

var parser_origin = 'http://xxxxxx.com';
var path_thumb1 = '/upload_menus/thumb1/' + id_establecimiento() +'/';
var img_tmpl = '/upload_tmpl/upload.jpg';


   //get data[] (array). 1er JSON. start
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v137/lacarte.restaurants.back/alacarte/php/r.shw.menu.php", { site: id_establecimiento(),idioma: to_translate(),traduccion: traduc_usada() }, function(data){

          for (var i=0, len=data.length; i < len; i++) {
              console.log(data[i]);
          }
              data = data['data']; 

    //get files{} (object) . 2nd JSON. start
    $.getJSON( parser_origin + "/_country/spain/v137/lacarte.restaurants.back/alacarte/php/r.shw.menu.php", { site: id_establecimiento(),idioma: to_translate(),traduccion: traduc_usada() }, function(files){ //files // ori

            for (var z=0, len=files.length; z < len; z++) {
              console.log(files[z]); //required!!
                }
            files = files['files']; 

// Now two nested $.each(), to iterate on 1st JSON and get objects of 2nd JSON. It`s work fine!

// 1st loop. sections 
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
collapsible.push(v.es_un); 

$.each(collapsible, function (i, v) {
    if ($.inArray(v, seccion) === -1) {
        seccion.push(v);
    }
    });
});

// 2nd loop. items into sections 
$.each(seccion, function (i, loc) {
var parent = loc;
var elements = '';

$.each(data, function (x, sub) {
    var subLoc = sub.nombre;
    var subLoc2 = sub.condimentos;
    var subLoc5 = sub.DT_RowId; 
    var subLoc6 = sub.alergeno; 
    var subLoc7 = sub.nota_item; 
    var subLoc8 = sub.image; 
    // check if have a picture  
      if  (subLoc8 == null || subLoc8 == '')   {
          var foto_mostrar_listview = img_tmpl;  // if not, assign a dummy image for not empty  
        }
      else if  (subLoc8 != null){// if, yes, get it 
          var foto_mostrar_listview = files.files_menus[subLoc8].web_path_thumb2;
        };

    var foto_f = '<img src="'+ foto_mostrar_listview +'" alt="img25"/>';        


    if (sub.es_un == parent) {

                elements += '<li class="ui-li-has-thumb ui-first-child">'+ foto_f +'<h2>'+ subLoc + '</h2><h3>' + subLoc2 + '<h3><p>' + '</p><h6><h6><h1 class="ui-li-aside" style="right:0.80em">' + '<i class="fa fa-hashtag" aria-hidden="true"></i>'+ '<span class="notranslate">' + items + '<span></h1>' + '</li><a href="#popupPhotoPortrait" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="imagen-go" id="' + subLoc8 + '"><span class="fontawesome"><i class="fa fa-search-plus fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></a></p>' 
                items++;  

    } //end if (sub.es_un)

});//$.each(data...)

$("#location-list").append($("<div/>").append($("<div/>", {
    "data-role": "collapsible", 
    "data-collapsed": "true", 
        "data-collapsed-icon": "carat-r", 
        "data-expanded-icon": "carat-d", 
        "class": parent,
        "style" : "margin : 8px 4px"  
}).append($("<h3/>").text(parent)).append($("<ul/>", { 
         "data-role": "listview", 
        "data-theme": "e",
        "data-count-theme": "b",
 }).append(elements).listview()))).collapsibleset('refresh');  

}); //$.each(seccion,...)

// funtion that detect click on button (take "id" value from JSON)
$('.imagen-go').click(function() {

        var id= $(this).attr("id"); 
        var extension =  ".jpg";
        document.getElementById('imagen-to-show').src = path_thumb1 + id + extension ;  // ori

}); // end ('.imagen-go')

    }); //fin del getJSON files{}
    });  //fin del getJSON data[]

});// end ( document ).on
```